# Appended object to a set is `NoneType` python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, random, set

I have a huge array of labels which I make unique via:

```
unique_train_labels = set(train_property_labels)
```

Which prints out as `set([u'A', u'B', u'C'])`. I want to create a new set of unique labels with a new label called "no_region", and am using:

```
unique_train_labels_threshold = unique_train_labels.add('no_region')
```

However, this prints out to be `None`.

My ultimate aim is to use these unique labels to later generate a random array of categorical labels via:

```
    rng = np.random.RandomState(101)

    categorical_random = rng.choice(list(unique_train_labels), len(finalTestSentences))
    categorical_random_threshold = rng.choice(list(unique_train_labels_threshold), len(finalTestSentences))
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) it says that `set.add()` should generate a new set, which seems not to be the case (hence I can't later call `list(unique_train_labels_threshold)`)

Comment: Where in the docs does it say that the add method generates a new set?  I only found:  *s.add(x)   add element x to set s*

Comment: you should do it int 2 time. first you store `unique_train_labels` in `unique_train_labels_threshold` then call `add()` on `unique_train_labels_threshold`, `a_set.add(stuff)` always `return none`

Comment: @cdarke yes this is what I meant, it says it adds an element to a set, which for me seems to imply the set should still be there..

Comment: @pwnsauce can you clarify what I can do so that I can use the new set `a_set.add(stuff)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in Moses' answer, the `set.add` method mutates the original set, it does not create a new set. In Python it's conventional for methods that perform in-place mutation to return `None`; the methods of all built-in mutable types do that, and the convention is generally observed by 3rd-party libraries.

An alternative to using the `.copy` method is to use the `.union` method, which returns a new set that is the union of the original set and the set supplied as an argument. For sets, the `|` *or* operator invokes the `.union` method.

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = a.union({5})
c = a | {4}
print(a, b, c)
```

**output**

```
{1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3, 5} {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

The `.union` method (like other set methods that can be invoked via operator syntax) has a slight advantage over the operator syntax: you can pass it *any* iterable for its argument; the operator version requires you to explicitly convert the argument to a set (or frozenset).

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = a.union([5, 6])
c = a | set([7, 8])
print(a, b, c)
```

**output**

```
{1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3, 5, 6} {1, 2, 3, 7, 8}
```

Using the explicit `.union` method is slightly more efficient here because it bypasses converting the arg to a set: internally, the method just iterates over the contents of the arg, adding them to the new set, so it doesn't care if the arg is a set, list, tuple, string, or dict.

From the official Python [set docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

> Note, the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(),
>   difference(), and symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset()
>   methods will accept any iterable as an argument. In contrast, their
>   operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets. This
>   precludes error-prone constructions like set('abc') & 'cbs' in favor
>   of the more readable set('abc').intersection('cbs').

Answer (score 4):

The set `add` method mutates the set *inplace* and returns a `None`.

You should do:

```
unique_train_labels_threshold = unique_train_labels.copy()
unique_train_labels_threshold.add('no_region')
```

Using `copy` ensures mutations on the new set are not propagated to the old one.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working - it still prints out to `None`.

Comment: You've somehow modified the original set to `None`. Recreate that first set

Comment: @DhruvGhulati this should work. i'm not sure the `copy()` is needed (i tried without in python3 and it worked just fine without)

Comment: @pwnsauce The changes you make to the *new* set will appear in the *old* one if you don't `copy`, which is not desirable in this case. Both of them will be referencing the same object without copy (so no new, no old, but same object)

Comment: @DhruvGhulati: Are you doing `unique_train_labels_threshold = unique_train_labels_threshold.add('no_region')`. That's wrong. It will update `unique_train_labels_threshold` the way you want, but then it will replace it with `None`.

Comment: Really odd, it doesn't. I never modified the original set...maybe it is because this whole thing is within a 
`if __name__ == "__main__":` function...or maybe because `train_property_labels` is used later on in my code (so I need to convert back to and forth from list/set?)

Comment: @PM2Ring yes I was..I guess that was it. OK!!

Comment: @MosesKoledoye that is true. When is the `copy()` not needed ? because for 'basic' object `=` make a copy right ?

Comment: @pwnsauce For *mutable* objects, assignment does not create a new copy, but a reference to the original object

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: The same is true of immutable objects too, but it generally doesn't matter because they're immutable. :) Eg, `a=(1,2,3); b=a; print(id(a),id(b))`

Comment: @PM2Ring Rightly so :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find in the documentation anywhere were it says that `add` generates a new set.
You need to copy the original, then add to the new copy.

```
import copy

unique_train_labels_threshold = copy.deepcopy(unique_train_labels)
unique_train_labels_threshold.add('no_region')
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working - it still prints out to `None`.

Comment: Using `deepcopy` on set elements is overkill. The `set.copy` method is always sufficient, since set elements have to be totally immutable. You can't even make a tuple of lists a set element.

Comment: @PM2Ring:  the reason I use it is because the doc specifically says that the `copy` method does a shallow copy.

Comment: And a shallow copy is perfectly adequate on totally immutable objects. IOW, any object that _needs_ deepcopy to be copied safely _cannot_ be a set element.

Comment: Of course, this is mostly irrelevant for the OP's case, since they just want a set of strings, which are clearly immutable.

Comment: But a mutable object can have a `__hash__` method.

Comment: All that a `set()` requires is that the objects are unique, and that they implement `__hash__` and `__eq__`.